# Does Netflix need kernel 3.17 to work?

Tags: kernel, netflix

I am wondering if I need to update my kernel in order to get Netflix to work in Chrome. I have the latest version of Chrome installed, but whenever I try to watch something on Netflix, it says "oops, something went wrong" with the error code M7063-1913. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you use the IE user agent and install the nss libraries (not the versions supplied in the software center)?  Chrome 37 worked fine for me with kernel 3.13...

Comment: @ubfan1 it says here there is no need to do all you describe: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/nss-updated-to-allow-native-html5.html

Comment: Have you checked the option "Prefer html5" in your account settings on Netflix?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing from the mirror of my country to the main server as the place to download updates from. I guess Canada just hasn't updated their repositories yet. So no, the 3.17 kernel is not needed for Netflix, just make sure that you have all the latest updates for your computer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with chrome and flashplugin for linux try opening netflix in firefox after doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

Or:

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo aptitude install flashplugin-nonfree
```

Comment: alternatively run chrome from wine and install siverlight